# MySQL foreign key constraints not being respected / honored

Tags: php, sql, magento, mysql

Having an issue with MySQL foreign key constraints not being respected / honored on mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.66, for unknown-linux-gnu (x86_64).

The database / table structure has **never been modified**, aka: this is the original and only table structure.

This is the result from a standard mysqldump.

```
-- Table structure for table `catalog_category_entity_int`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `catalog_category_entity_int`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_int` (
`value_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`entity_type_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`attribute_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`value_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `IDX_BASE` (`entity_type_id`,`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`),
KEY `FK_ATTRIBUTE_INT_ENTITY` (`entity_id`),
KEY `FK_CATALOG_CATEGORY_EMTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE` (`attribute_id`),
KEY `FK_CATALOG_CATEGORY_EMTITY_INT_STORE` (`store_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOG_CATEGORY_EMTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOG_CATEGORY_EMTITY_INT_ENTITY` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOG_CATEGORY_EMTITY_INT_STORE` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1483 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

**See:**

**UNIQUE KEY `IDX_BASE` (`entity_type_id`,`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`)**

```
Error:
Query:
INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_int` VALUES (1,3,32,0,2,1),(2,3,32,1,2,1),(6,3,32,0,4,1),[...];

MySQL said: Documentation
#1062 - Duplicate entry '3-144-40-0' for key 'IDX_BASE'
```

I have never seen this happen, any idea on how this is possible?

Comment: Is this not just you putting the same entry for `IDX_BASE`? You have defined it as unique. What does this have to do with foreign keys?

Comment: your databse is likely not actually using InnoDB. This is the only possibility as to why MySQL would not respect a constraint such as foreign key. I had some trouble myself getting innodb to work properly...

Comment: thatidiotguy - Correct, I should have stated that unique and the foreign key constraints linking to this table are not functioning.  However, I solved this issue.  See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to replicate this was turning off foreign / unique checks on data import with:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;
```

This must have been set on import at some point.  Not sure why anyone would do this, but, that must have been what happened.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin usually creates export files with this specification especially if you want to re-import the same file after an initial import fails -- and pick up where you left of instead of doing all the work again which would be bad for 2+ GB files.